# Need Sticky Header/Footer but CMS won't let me code in the body tag

Tags: html, css, header, footer, sticky

I work in an outdated content management system that doesn't give me access to the body tag. Is there any way to create a sticky footer and sticky header without using the body tag?

Comment: Way too broad. You need to add a lot more detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you can put something in the head element, this should do it:

```
<script>
var myStickyHeader = document.createElement('div');
myStickyHeader.style.background = 'white';
myStickyHeader.style.position = 'fixed';
myStickyHeader.style.top = 0;
myStickyHeader.style.left = 0;
myStickyHeader.style.right = 0;
myStickyHeader.style.zIndex = 9999; // just in case
myStickyHeader.innerHTML = 'My sticky header';


document.body.addEventListener('load', function() {
    document.body.insertBefore(myStickyHeader, document.body.firstChild);
}, false);
</script>
```

switch `myStickyHeader.style.top` for `myStickyHeader.style.bottom` for a footer.